# Is possible to list the files affected by pre-commit run?

Tags: pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

While using [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/#usage) sometimes I just want to know that filenames are going to be passed to the hook, just to verify that by `--from-ref` and `to-ref` are correct. For example, I was running:

```
pre-commit run flake8  --from-ref $(git merge-base master HEAD) --to-ref HEAD
```

and I wasn't sure of what files where passed to my `flake8` hook, adding `--verbose` does not help because `flake8` will not output the filenames either.

So it's there any way to tell `pre-commit` to only output the list of filenames without running the actual hook?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

pre-commit provides a special [`identity`](https://pre-commit.com/#meta-identity) hook for this purpose

you can configure it by doing:

```yaml
-   repo: meta
    hooks:
    -   id: identity
```

alternatively, if you're just trying to figure out `--from-ref` / `--to-ref` -- you can use `git diff A...B --name-only` as that's what pre-commit is using behind the scenes

---

disclaimer: I'm the author of pre-commit

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you can define a new hook in your `.pre-commit-config.yaml` that runs `ls`

```
- id: ls
  name: show files
  language: system
  entry: "ls"
  pass_filename: true
```

Then you can run:

```
git add .pre-commit-config.yaml
git commit # so that the new config takes effect
pre-commit run ls --verbose --from-ref $(git merge-base master HEAD) --to-ref HEAD
```

and you will get a list of the files "selected" by `pre-commit`.